# In which table I can see Keyword Metadata Information in Broker Db?

Tags: broker, keyword, metadata

We have keywords which have Metadata Schema and some values in the Keyword metadata. Is there any specific table where I can see Metadata info for the Keywords? I can see one Entry in Custom_Meta table but it does not have any info about the Metadata of that Keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All custom metadata info, including for keywords gets stored in `Custom-Meta` table only.

Have you published the Category of the missing Keyword metadata in broker db?

Comment: thanks @shahid, yes i was missing publishing.

Comment: @Neelesh Raghuvanshi, in that case please accept the answer so the question becomes closed